# What's the flavor profile of a beer that only uses bittering and dry hops?

Tags: dry-hop

It's of course possible, but I'd appreciate any experience anyone has with **only** dry-hopping for finishing hops.  That would mean:

1. add the bittering hops
2. chill, aerate, pitch, ferment as usual
3. dry-hop for some number of days in secondary or keg

Have you done this?

Comment: Great question, although the answers might be a bit subjective depending on a LOT of factors. However, I am curious how such a schedule turns out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done that quite a few times.  It ends up kinda like you'd expect...a tiny bit of flavor from the bittering hops and great aroma from the dry hops.  You can definitely make a really good beer like that if you plan your recipe around it.

Answer (score 1):

I did a FWH and a flame out one time. I didn't care for it. It was odd lacking in flavor with the aroma there.